# Search Bar Cancel Button don´t work in ios 7 sometimes

Tags: ios, ios7, tableview, uisearchbar

Cancel button in search bar don´t work in iOS 7 when search bar is initially hidden.

I follow this tutorial to create a search bar in tableview:

[raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view)

There are a example project in this tutorial, is better use this project than my explanation :)

In iOS 5 and 6 works fine. 
I have reviewed all delegates.

There are two possibilities. The first is to press the button when the bar is hidden, the second is to press the button when the bar is displayed (moving the table down with a gesture you can see the search bar)

If search bar is hidden initially cancel button don´t work, it don't call calcel delegate method:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Sorry I can not explain it better.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]; only works when the search bar is already visible.

Comment: Yes, because my search bar is always visible now.

Answer (score 3):

I googled all over internet and couldn't find a solution. so i changed the UItableview behaviour.

instead of  `[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];` I scroll down the tableview.

```
- (IBAction)goToSearch:(id)sender {

 scroll down to show the table.
//    CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
//    newBounds.origin.y =0;
//    
//    self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
//[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

    CGPoint contentOffset=self.tableView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y=0;
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];


}
```

in my ViewDidload:

```
//        CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
//        newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + searchBar.bounds.size.height;
        // self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;

        CGPoint contentOffset=self.tableView.contentOffset;
        contentOffset.y=self.tableView.bounds.origin.y + searchBar.bounds.size.height;
        self.tableView.contentOffset=contentOffset;
```

If found for some reasons, in iOS 7 , change table view bounds cause search bar to disappear.
Hope that helps.

Comment: it works for me. maybe you can post some codes into the questions?

Answer (score 1):

That code work for me on iOS7:

```
- (IBAction)goToSearch:(id)sender {
  [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
  [candySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your project it will work i have tested and it is working correctly

```
 -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchbar
{
[searchbar resignFirstResponder];

for (UIView *possibleButton in searchbar.subviews)
{
    if ([possibleButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)possibleButton;
        cancelButton.enabled = YES;
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to come from the new behaviour of the translucent property in a navigation bar.

Since iOS 7 navigation bars are translucent by default. And it looks like it's overlapping the search bar when you display it after pressing a button.

Try to set in your controller:

```
float osVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (osVersion >= 7.0)
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

This should quickly solve the problem.

But I think for a better fix you should see the [iOS 7 transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) where they explain how to handle translucent navigation bars.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have set `_searchBar.delegate = self` and implemented `UISearchBarDelegate` in your class.

This is how you do it:

```
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{                     // called when cancel button pressed
    searchBar.text = nil;

    //hide cancel button
    [_searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```